# Data is plural?

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, lateral-thinking

The three overlapping ellipses form seven curved regions.  Your task is to place exactly one tile per region, so that the four tiles in any one ellipse can solve the corresponding clue!

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The answers

> Send (e.g. data) TR AN SM IT

> e.g. Data HE LM SM AN

> Helps Burns SM IT HE RS

Or visually

> [image: Solution]

Comment: Well done! Finally you got some good fortune this time and didn’t get sniped! 